# Preg_Replace: variable substitution and removing all non-local urls

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've looked around for a few hours but the examples I've found didn't push me to a place where I could logically come up with what I needed so I think I need something more specific to accommodate for my ignorance and to ask my nerdy coder brothern for help.

**Problem**:

1) I want to make a very specific url replaced by some markup but using the id as a variable (as seen in the example below).

2) I have a text parser and I only want it to allow links to my domain (currently not implemented), any other link will be removed (currently implemented with some strpos/strip_tags action) but I'd  like to use `preg_replace` to allow links to my domain.

For a psuedo example (using parts of the url as a var):

```
$markup = '[[-$0-]]';
$domain = 'mydomain.com';
$comment = 'This is my link example for http://mydomain.com/plan/43434 and Ii am confused';
$comment = preg_replace('&\bhttp://' . $mydomain . '/plan/(\d+)/"', $markup, $comment);
echo $comment:
```

Desired Output:

```
This is my link example for [[-43434-]] and I am confused
```

Then after this code has executed I would do the removal all links but my those of my own domain. I'm not really sure how to pull this one off at all, but I could use some love.

Answer (score 0):

## Description

This regex will:

- find your the urls and replace them with marked up text
- assumes the url will be start with `http://mydomain.com/plan` as shown in the sample text

Regex: `((?:(?!http:\/\/mydomain\.com\/plan\/).)*)http:\/\/mydomain\.com\/plan\/(\S*)`

Replace with: `$1[[-$2-]]`

[image]

## Example

**Sample Text**

```
This http://mydomain.com/plan/12345 is my link example for http://mydomain.com/plan/43434 and I am confused
```

**Code**

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
echo preg_replace('/((?:(?!http:\/\/mydomain\.com\/plan\/).)*)http:\/\/mydomain.com\/plan\/(\S*)/mx','$1[[-$2-]]',$sourcestring);
?>
```

**Sourcestring after replacement**

```
This [[-12345-]] is my link example for [[-43434-]] and I am confused
```

Comment: That is badass! That's precisely what I needed although I'd like a second preg_replace to allow other urls of my domain to remain in tact while obliterating non-local urls.

That being said the example you gave was the far more pressing matter, thank you very much!